# Mulesoft Insertion into Mongo DB database

Tags: mongodb, mule-studio, mlab

I am using a Mongo DB connector to insert data into Mongo Instance located in mLab.
I am sure I am using the correct credentials since these credentials are working when I am using them through a Java code.
But here using the Mongo DB connector constantly throws me an error as can be seen below.

> org.mule.api.ConnectionException: Couldn't connect with the given
>   credentials org.mule.api.ConnectionException: Couldn't connect with
>   the given credentials at
>   org.mule.module.mongo.MongoCloudConnector.getDatabase(MongoCloudConnector.java:1304)
>   at
>   org.mule.module.mongo.MongoCloudConnector.connect(MongoCloudConnector.java:1173)
>   at
>   org.mule.module.mongo.connectivity.MongoCloudConnectorConnectionFactory.makeObject(MongoCloudConnectorConnectionFactory.java:56)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
>   at
>   org.mule.module.mongo.connectivity.MongoCloudConnectorConnectionManager.acquireConnection(MongoCloudConnectorConnectionManager.java:361)
>   at
>   org.mule.module.mongo.connectivity.MongoCloudConnectorConnectionManager.test(MongoCloudConnectorConnectionManager.java:444)
>   at
>   org.mule.tooling.metadata.api.utils.ConnectionTester.internalTestConnection(ConnectionTester.java:88)
>   at
>   org.mule.tooling.metadata.api.utils.ConnectionTester.testConnectionFor(ConnectionTester.java:113)
>   at

Is there something that I am missing here?

Below is the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:mongo="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo/current/mule-mongo.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="developers.zomato.com" port="80" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration1" host="api.mlab.com" port="80" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
    <mongo:config name="Mongo_DB" password="XXXXX" database="restaurant_data" host="ds241039.mlab.com" port="41039" doc:name="Mongo DB" username="XxXx"/>
    <flow name="rest-webservice-applicationFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/rest" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="api/v2.1/search" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:query-param paramName="entity_id" value="1"/>
                <http:query-param paramName="entity_type" value="city"/>
                <http:header headerName="user-key" value="XXXXXXXXX"/>
            </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" metadata:id="13f7b603-ac1e-45b4-9950-32c39a20ee36">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/json"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    results_found: payload.results_found,
    results_start: payload.results_start,
    results_shown: payload.results_shown,
    restaurants: payload.restaurants map ((restaurant , indexOfRestaurant) -> {
        restaurant: {
            R: restaurant.restaurant.R,
            id: restaurant.restaurant.id,
            name: restaurant.restaurant.name,
            url: restaurant.restaurant.url,
            location: restaurant.restaurant.location,
            switch_to_order_menu: restaurant.restaurant.switch_to_order_menu,
            cuisines: restaurant.restaurant.cuisines,
            average_cost_for_two: restaurant.restaurant.average_cost_for_two,
            price_range: restaurant.restaurant.price_range,
            currency: restaurant.restaurant.currency,
            offers: restaurant.restaurant.offers map ((offer , indexOfOffer) -> offer),
            thumb: restaurant.restaurant.thumb,
            user_rating: restaurant.restaurant.user_rating,
            photos_url: restaurant.restaurant.photos_url,
            menu_url: restaurant.restaurant.menu_url,
            featured_image: restaurant.restaurant.featured_image,
            has_online_delivery: restaurant.restaurant.has_online_delivery,
            is_delivering_now: restaurant.restaurant.is_delivering_now,
            deeplink: restaurant.restaurant.deeplink,
            has_table_booking: restaurant.restaurant.has_table_booking,
            events_url: restaurant.restaurant.events_url
        }
    })
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <mongo:json-to-dbobject doc:name="Mongo DB"/>
        <mongo:insert-object config-ref="Mongo_DB" doc:name="Mongo DB" collection="restaurant"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Can you share the related xml definition?

Comment: @rodrigoap You can see the config XML above.

Comment: Could it be that the authentication database is different from the payload database?

Comment: I do not think so, I got the same database authenticated using the same URI, username, password from a java-based client which I am currently using instead of the Mongo DB connector, to store data to Mongo DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB connector uses the deprecated MONGODB-CR authentication mechanism, MLab is expecting the SCRAM-SHA-1 mechanism.

The SCRAM-SHA-1 mechanism is available in the enterprise version of Mulesoft ESB.

The connection URI configuration is available on version 4.2.0 and above. This is how you configure it:

Add the connector to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-mongo-connector</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Configure a connection in your flow:

```
<mongo:config-connection-string name="MongoDB_Config" 
    connectionString="mongodb://jdoe:myPass@localhost:27017?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1"/>
```

Comment: I am not sure about this. But yes, I am sure, that almost all the latest Mongo DB deployments use SCRAM-SHA-1 for authentication. How do you say that this connector uses CR ? Anyway we can initiate a SCRAM-SHA-1 using this connector?

Comment: Can you set a connection URI in the connector like this? mongodb://jdoe:myPass@localhost:27017?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1

Comment: I do not know how to do this in Anypoint Studio. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It looks like Mule 4 has connection URI: https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/mongodb-connector-reference#config_connection-string

Comment: I took a look at the connector's code and found that the connection URI configuration is available in 4.2.0 and above. I added a usage example.

Comment: yes..thank you I will try that out. I currently have only mule 3.9. So I will probably not be able to try it out. Thanks a lot though.